# handle log messages with newlines

Tags: python, logging

At the moment we handle log message from our python scripts like this:

- script writes output to text files with FileHandler.
- a check-logfiles tool filters out all INFO messages
- the result gets sent to us by mail (custom solution, does not use the logging module).

This works well, but if there are newlines in the log message, this does not work, since the check-logfiles tool works line based.

Example:

```
logger.info('foo\nbar')
```

Example output:

```
2014-07-10 11:52:11 foo.utils.importutils: INFO    [18473] foo
bar
```

The `foo` line gets filtered, but `bar` gets mailed to us.

How to handle this better? I want `foo\nbar` be handled like **one** message.

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to mail log handler. You shall provide more details about that handler.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky we don't use the mail log handler. I updated the question. We log to files. Does my question still need more details?

Comment: Is `check-logfiles` your own tool that you can change, or is it some third-party tool that you can't configure?

Comment: @VinaySajip `check-logfiles` is our custom tool. But I would prefer a solution where we don't need to work with text files any more. We could do some magic to see if a line in the logfiles is a continuation, but that is just dirty guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Consider using log mail handler

e.g. with `logbook` package, [logbook.MailHandler](http://pythonhosted.org/Logbook/api/handlers.html#logbook.MailHandler) handler can handle even complex log records, there is even an option to set up template, rendering e-mail content based on logged record attributes.

The log record in this case holds log message in a structure, which does not suffer from new lines mess as if you write the logs to text file.

Python stdlib logging also provides [SMTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler), but here I cannot serve with real experience.

Comment: Can `logbook` handle structured messages, too? With structured I mean: something like: days_left=5 and the output can be put into a DB at the receiving host.

Comment: @guettli `logbook` allows extended properties of the log record and the record can be easily sent to remote server, e.g. using zeromq (such solution is built in). There is [ticketingHandler](http://pythonhosted.org/Logbook/api/ticketing.html#logbook.ticketing.TicketingHandler), which writes data into database.